# Redis-protobuf: Err type mismatch seen with protos having nested messages

Tags: c++, redis, protocol-buffers

When there are more than one proto files with nested messages loaded by libredis-protobuf.so, unable to set any fields of the second proto message. Both proto files are proto3 version.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> PB.SCHEMA Msg   
"message Msg {\n  int32 i = 1;\n  .SubMsg sub = 2;\n  repeated int32 arr = 3;\n}\n"    
127.0.0.1:6379> PB.SET key Msg '{"i" : 1, "sub" : {"s" : "string", "i" : 2}, "arr" : [1, 2, 3]}'   
(integer) 1   
127.0.0.1:6379> PB.GET key --FORMAT JSON Msg   
"{\"i\":1,\"sub\":{\"s\":\"string\",\"i\":2},\"arr\":[1,2,3]}"    
127.0.0.1:6379>    
127.0.0.1:6379> PB.SCHEMA Rsg2   
"message Rsg2 {\n  int32 i = 1;\n  .SubRsg2 sub = 2;\n  repeated int32 arr = 3;\n}\n"    
127.0.0.1:6379>    
127.0.0.1:6379> PB.SET key Rsg2 '{"i" : 1, "sub" : {"s" : "string", "i" : 2}, "arr" : [10, 20, 30]}'   
(error) ERR type mismatch  
127.0.0.1:6379>   
127.0.0.1:6379> PB.SET key Rsg2 /i 10   
(error) ERR type missmatch    
127.0.0.1:6379> PB.SET key Rsg2 /arr/0 2   
(error) ERR type missmatch    
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Same issue seen when using protobuf-3.8.0-map-reflection.tar.gz and latest protobuf. Any help/info appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you've already set `key` as an object of `Msg` type. When you try to set `key` to an object of another type, e.g. `Rsg2`, it returns error reply: *type mismatch*. It behaviors like trying to set a key of which the type is HASH.

You need to delete the key, and then you can set it to an object of another type. Or just setting another key.

```
PB.SET another-key Rsg2 '{"i" : 1, "sub" : {"s" : "string", "i" : 2}, "arr" : [10, 20, 30]}'
```

B.T.W. there's a plan to set (key, value) pair without checking the type, i.e. an option: --FORCE.

Comment: Thanks that works. When using nested messages, should we still continue to use protobuf-3.8.0-map-reflection.tar.gz  or the latest version protobuf?

Comment: You need to use protobuf-3.8.0-map-reflection.tar.gz, since the latest protobuf still lack full support for map reflection.

Comment: In my use-case, I need to use nested and repeated messages. 

Questions:
1. If I use the latest protobuf (v25.1) when I have nested and repeated messages, what does not work? Performance will be bad?
2. Or is usage of “protobuf-3.8.0-map-reflection.tar.gz” is a must until “full support for map reflection in latest protobuf” for my use-case?

Trying to understand the level of dependency on 3.8.0 version of protobuf for my use-case. Appreciate your support.

Comment: Yes, protobuf 3.8.0-map-reflection is a must. Because this version of protobuf modified the source code to support map reflection. Why you need a higher version of protobuf?

Comment: On our system a later version of protobuf library is already in use by another application, we can't have have two different versions of the same library. These applications are not containerized.  If our application is having simple message structures, with NO nested and repeated message structures then can we use later/latest version of protobuf library?

Comment: protobuf format is compatible with older version, and the protobuf lib used for redis-protobuf won't be compile or link with your other systems. So it won't be a problem. If you indeed want a later version of protobuf, you can try to build with it. If it passes building, and you don't need map reflection, it should work.